# Cannot install pyqt5 for python3.4 on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, python-3.4, pyqt5

I tried to install PyQt5 on Windows 10 for python 3.4 with pip using this code on cmd

`pip install pyqt5`

it answers

```
Collecting pyqt5
Using cached PyQt5-5.8-5.8.0-cp34.cp35.cp36.cp37-none-win-amd64.whl
```

but I received this error

```
Could not find a version the satisfies the requirement sip>=4.19.1 <from pyqt5> <from versions: > 
No matching distribution found for sip>=4.19.1 <from pyqt5>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you can install PyQt5 via pip only from Python 3.5 and later. 
Since you are using Python 3.4, you can upgrade Python or download the windows  executable (32 bit or 64 bit) for example from this [site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.4.1/).

Here, you can find the link from [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html):

Answer (score 0):

You can download your answer from here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.4.1/